# Why i'm not seeing branch merged in Source tree?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

As a single resource I'm working in project. I've created a branch from master today and committed some change in it. Later I merged the new branch in master. I can see the new branch changes in master branch but can't see the same graph as mentioned [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-sourcetree-brances-to-merge-an-update/)

master branch:

[image]

newly merged branch:

[image]

Whats wrong with the graph? is there any setting to view as I expected ?

**EDIT 1:**

This is how i merged the branch:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Well, according to those screenshots, you have not merged. You say "newly merged branch", which branch were you expecting to be shown as merged into which other branch?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, `blog_changes` is the branch which has been merged in `master`. So i wanted to see  `blog_changes` merged in `master`

Comment: OK, question. While you were working on `blog_changes`, was any changes made to master? That is, after you created `blog_changes` from master until the point where you merged? If not, then what you did was a fast-forward merge, which simply moves the branch pointer forward, it does not create a merge commit which creates those parallel railroad type of diagrams.

Comment: You can merge without using fast-forward if you so wish, but you need to decide if you want the extra merge commits just for the purpose of making your merges more visible in your history.

Comment: No, I'm only the person who works in all branches.

Comment: Then almost certainly you did a fast-forward merge. It does not create a merge commit, it simply moves the master branch pointer forward so that the commits are also part of master. If you want or need the merge commit, to make merges visible, you can specify `--no-ff` when merging, and there is likely an option in SourceTree for this as well.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Not sure how to do that. I've edited my question which shows how i did merge the branch.

Comment: I just got a problem when merging just doesn't work, SourceTree says it  did, but no changes applied

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3778649/zaporozhchenko-oleksandr, raising pr and Merging code from bitbucket would be right approach. That is what I tried